# Why I get address instead of values , in C++ code?

Tags: c++

My code read a sparse matrix from a *.mtx file, and should print the matrix at console(only for test, for real case I want to return sparse matrix), but he print the address not the values.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct MatriceRara

{

  int *Linie, *Coloana, *Valoare;


  int nrElemente, nrLinii, nrColoane;

};


MatriceRara Read(const char* mtx) {

const char * mtx_file = mtx;

ifstream fin(mtx_file);

MatriceRara matR;
int nrElemente, nrLinii, nrColoane;

// skip header:
while (fin.peek() == '%') fin.ignore(2048, '\n');

// read parameters:
fin >> nrLinii >> nrColoane >> nrElemente;
matR.nrElemente = nrElemente;
matR.nrLinii = nrLinii;
matR.nrColoane = nrColoane;
cout << "Number of rows: " << matR.nrLinii <<endl;
cout << "Number of columns: " << matR.nrColoane << endl;
cout << "Number of not null values: " << matR.nrElemente << endl;


for (int i = 0; i< nrElemente; i++)
{

  int *m ,*n,*data;
  fin >> (int &) m >> (int &) n >> (int &) data;
  matR.Linie = m;
  matR.Coloana = n;
  matR.Valoare = data;
  //only for test:
  cout<<matR.Linie << " " << matR.Coloana << " " << matR.Valoare <<endl;



}

//return matR;
}



int main () {


MatriceRara a = Read("Amica.mtx");


}
```

My output:

```
Number of rows: 5
Number of columns: 5
Number of not null values: 8
0x7fff00000001 0x7f4400000001 0x1
0x7fff00000000 0x7f4400000001 0x1
0x7fff00000000 0x7f4400000001 0x1
0x7fff00000000 0x7f4400000001 0x1
0x7fff00000000 0x7f4400000001 0x1
0x7fff00000000 0x7f4400000001 0x1
0x7fff00000000 0x7f4400000001 0x1
0x7fff00000000 0x7f4400000001 0x1
```

So, as you can see in my output, it's print the address, not the values.
Thanks very much !

Comment: Because you are outputting pointers.

Comment: `int *m ,*n,*data; fin >> (int &) m >> (int &) n >> (int &) data;` is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @drescherjm I hope too. I think the OP tried to minimize its code.

Answer (score 4):

You declared the following members as pointers to int:

```
int *Linie, *Coloana, *Valoare;
```

Then you print these pointers:

```
cout<<matR.Linie << " " << matR.Coloana << " " << matR.Valoare <<endl;
```

So you get what you asked: pointer's values (e.g. addresses)

Answer (score 1):

Because the variables `Linie`,`Coloana` and `Valoare` are pointers.

You have to dereference the pointers by preceding a `*`.

```
int value;
value = *m;
```

and if you want to print the values, again here:

```
cout<< *matR.Linie << " " << *matR.Coloana << " " << *matR.Valoare << endl;
```

Answer (score -4):

All your variables and class members of type `int *` should really be of type `int`. Currently they are uninitialized pointers, while they are really intended to be integer numbers.

Comment: Why do you declare as pointers in the first place? Here, in this example, they should be of type int rather than pointer-to-int. In your original code, you a) declared three uninitialized pointers; b) used them (not the undefined locations they point to uninitialized) as integer locations.
Linie, Coloana and Valoare should be `int`s too, in your current code they are just uninitialized pointers.